# Floating point error in representation?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, double-precision

when i make this multiplication

> 0.94 * 8700

the output is

> 8177.999999999999

but it should have been

> 8178

i'm using java , but i don't think this error is related to a particular Programming language
now my question is ... why this happened ?? 
 and what other numbers (just as an example) cause the same error?

Comment: Here's a pretty good overview of how floating point works: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems
There's 10 kinds of people in the world : those who understand binary and those who don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific reason in your case is that the real number 0.94 cannot be represented exactly in a double precision floating point. When you type `0.94`, the actual number stored is `0.939999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an error. IEEE floats can't represent decimal numbers exactly.