# Fortran number formatting

Tags: loops, double, fortran, rounding

I am using Intel® Visual Fortran Compiler Professional Edition 11.1 and when I run this code

```
program Console1
implicit none

real(8), parameter:: iterations = 1000.d0
real(8), parameter:: maximum = 0.02d0

integer, parameter:: outfile=1

real(8) force, dforce
integer i

dforce = maximum/iterations
force = 0.d0

open (unit=outfile,file="results.txt",action="write",status="replace")
do i=0,int(iterations)
    write(outfile, *) force
    force = force+dforce
enddo
close(outfile)

endprogram
```

the file results.txt is a mess, the final number is 1.999999999999952E-002 rather than 2.d-2

what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: 1.999999999999952E-002 *is*  2.d-2.  Learn about binary floating point.

Comment: I changed your title from "what is wrong with Fortran?" because that can be a little inflammatory, and it isn't specific enough to help attract folks who can answer your question.

Comment: @Paul: better to say "is floating-point representation of real number 0.02 on your machine."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point error in representation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581741/floating-point-error-in-representation)

Comment: If you search this site for "floating point error", you'll find a million people who are having the same problem in every language on every type of computer.

Comment: This is why non-programmers should not program. This is CS 101. Not your fault, just accept that you are missing basic fundamentals, and banging some code in a computer does not make you a programmer.

Comment: same comments as above, so (1) take some textbook and learn the basics, (2) use the `inquire` statement to get a valid unit number.

Answer (score 9):

Not again! Floating point numbers are not exact representations of real numbers. Period.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 4):

Neither you nor fortran is doing anything wrong.  You are coming up against a fundamental limit of how arithmetic is done computationally.

The computer is storing the number "force" with limited precision, in binary, not as an exact fraction or decimal.  The exact value is never used - only a certain level of accuracy is reached.

The link that kemiisto posted explains in more detail, but the main thing to take from it is the mantra: "real (floating point) numbers are never exact".  It means that whenever you need to compare two reals, unless they have some very specific value like zero, then you need to check if they are close, not identical.

You can modify how the number is printed out at the end using format specifiers:
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the division is not exact in binary, right?

Comment: with iterations = 1000.d0 and maximum = 1.d0 the last number *is* 2.d0

Comment: No operation on float numbers is exact - including addition, subtraction, you name it.  In a few special cases where things can be perfectly represented in binary (or just by chance sometimes) things round off perfectly, but you should never rely on that.

Comment: The root of the problem is that not every real number is exactly representable in floating point format irregardless of the base. As far as I remember having the base x you can represent exactly numbers of the form [significant digits * x^exponent].

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to suggest that it was an issue with binary, rather that it's floating point.  And I think the OP needs to appreciate that there is nothing they can do about it!

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question:

the statement

```
write(outfile, *) force
```

uses what Fortran calls 'list-directed I/O'.  The '*' leaves it to the compiler to figure out a reasonable format for the output of the variable 'force'.  If you want to control the format of your output, use Fortran's edit descriptors.  For example

```
write(outfile, '(f6.3)') force
```

will format the number according to the descriptor 'f6.3' -- which is not quite what the questioner wants, but I hope it will put her on the right track.

Comment: it's unclear from the question what exactly the questioner wants, if it is a formatting problem or not

Comment: Well, I just read 'Fortran number formatting' and thought that the topic was Fortran number formatting.  But English is not my first language so I may have missed some of the subtleties of the wording.