# new Float("0.333") converts my 0.333 0.333+(14 more decimal places)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point error in representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581741/floating-point-error-in-representation)

So I am running this code to read float string values from a a file and store the values in to an array. When the program reads in "0.333" from the file it creates a new float value but the value is converted into 0.33329999446868896! Why is this? And how can I fix this issue? The matrices are declared as follows:

```
this.matrix = new double[this.getRow()][this.getCol()];
this.bMatrix = new double[this.getRow()];  

try {
        // make sure no blank lines at the end of the file.
        for (int i = 0; (strLine = reader.readLine()) != null; i++) {  
            System.out.println("Line from file #" + i + " " + strLine);
            String[] columns = strLine.trim().split("\\s+");
            for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                if (j < (columns.length - 1)) {
                    //A-matrix
                    this.matrix[i][j] = new Float(columns[j]).floatValue();
                    System.out.println("Element added to A-matrix: " + columns[j]);
                } else {
                    // B-matrix
                    bMatrix[i] = new Float(columns[j]).floatValue();
                    System.out.println("Element added to B-matrix: " + columns[j]);

                }
            }
        }
        showMatrix();
    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        reader.close();

    }
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: That a multi-duplicate. Let's search for it. Before we find, here's an element : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: But 0.33329999446868896 is too far from 0.333.  Float should have 23 binary digit precision. Are they really the same problem?

Comment: @Gene yes, a float only has ~8 _decimal_ digits of precision.

Comment: It seems like that was just a typo and the poster meant to write 0.3333

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is obligatory. http://floating-point-gui.de/ is easier to understand

Comment: Don't use `new Float` or `new Double` to parse a double, its both inaccurate and inefficient. Try `Double.parseDouble` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the way floating point numbers are represented in binary. Essentially, you can't precisely represent 0.333. The closest you can get is the number you see. If you want a shorter version for printing, use StringFormatter or something before you output your values.

Comment: Wow. I was hoping that wasn't the case. I need the exact number for future calculations. So there is no way I can get 0.333 into my new Float() value?

Comment: @Michael If precision is extremely important to you, use a `BigDecimal`, floating point calculations are by their nature inaccurate.

Comment: None whatsoever with Java primitives. There must be numerical libraries out there that deal with this, but they will be orders of magnitude slower to use.