# Sum Float number c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point error in representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581741/floating-point-error-in-representation)

I have problem with this code

```
int cent;
int dollar ;
float cnt2dlr;
 //convert cnt to doloar ;
cnt2dlr=(cnt)/(100);
```

The problem is when `cnt = 175`, `cnt2dlr = 0.17,444444` and not `0.17,5`

Any help?

Comment: With regards to this question your nickname is funny :)

Comment: I find it odd that it's off by that much though...

Comment: The [long answer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Can you post your full code? Where are you printing the 0.17444...?

Comment: There are 100 cents on a dollar, not 1000.
Also make sure that you perform floating point division. `175/1000` is `0` in c, while `175/1000.0` is `0.175` (subject to floating point representation errors).

Comment: You sure that wasn't 0.17499999? Then it would be round-off/representation error because floating point arithmetic is not real arithmetic.

Comment: Doing a quick calculation using 24 bits of precision, it should be close to 2936013/2 ^ 24 = 0.17500001192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not exact representations. They are approximations, so you cannot guarantee much precision. Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

To increase the precision of the numbers, consider using a 64-bit `double` instead of a 32-bit `float`.

Answer (score 7):

Floating point numbers are often inexact. There is nothing you can do about it.

Your code is a good illustration of why you should not use floating point numbers for calculations involving money. Just because currency values have a decimal point does **not** make money a floating point quantity. Floating points should be used for quantities which vary infinitesimally, like temperature or speed, not for quantities which vary in chunks, like money.

Comment: But 32 bit floats still have more precision than that... I find it odd that it's off by so much.

Comment: @CookieOfFortune Very true, but its not real code that was posted, so who can say. And if he's really converting cents to dollars by dividing by 1000 then his program has other problems.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you, but 24 bits of precision for 32 bit floats means the number should be really close to: 2936013/2 ^ 24 = 0.17500001192

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit puzzled. If you mean (cent) instead of (cnt), then

```
cnt2dlr=(cent)/(1000);
```

(note the e in cent) is an int / int division, and 175 / 1000 should return int 0.

Do you get the same result if you do, eg

```
cnt2dlr=(cent)/(1000.0);
```

note the decimal point.